# Unable to install pytest in windows 10 using pip 18.1 python 3.7.2

Tags: python, pip

Python 3.7.2 64 bit windows 10, 
pip 18.1

I am trying to do pip install pytest.  Getting error :                                     Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pytest/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytest.                                           Tried creating pip.ini file also under pip folder but did not work.

Comment: Do you have any proxy configured?

Comment: No proxy configured